How do I set up sshd on my server such that it only allows password login from within the LAN?
I have a home server running NixOS and I'm tired of enabling and disabling password authentication each time I want to add a new machine's ssh key (I tend to factory reset my machines pretty often...), so I thought allowing SSH using a password but only from my LAN is a good compromise. I tried googling around and came across several sources mentioning Match Address to enable using a password just for specific addresses, but it doesn't seem to work for me (it lets me input a password, but always denies it).
This is the module I use for SSH:
{
  services.openssh = {
    enable = true;
    ports = [ 22 ];
    settings = {
      PasswordAuthentication = false;
      AllowUsers = [ "user" ];
      PermitRootLogin = "no";
      UsePAM = true;
    };
    extraConfig = ''
      Match Address 192.168.0.0/24
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
    '';
  };

}

This is journalctl -u sshd (when trying to input the password 3 times before being kicked out):
Oct 04 08:57:07 nixos sshd[27362]: Failed password for user from 192.168.0.107 port 57276 ssh2
Oct 04 08:57:09 nixos sshd[27362]: Failed password for user from 192.168.0.107 port 57276 ssh2
Oct 04 08:57:16 nixos sshd[27362]: Failed password for user from 192.168.0.107 port 57276 ssh2
Oct 04 08:57:16 nixos sshd[27362]: Connection closed by authenticating user user 192.168.0.107 port 57276 [preauth]

This is the resulting sshd_config:
AllowUsers user
AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
GatewayPorts no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
KexAlgorithms sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
LogLevel INFO
Macs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin no
PrintMotd no
StrictModes yes
UseDns no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding no
Banner none

AddressFamily any
Port 22





Subsystem sftp /nix/store/1m888byzaqaig6azrrfpmjdyhgfliaga-openssh-9.7p1/libexec/sftp-server

AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/%u


HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key


Match Address 192.168.0.0/24
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

I tried:

With and without UsePAM
With and without ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
Using 192.168.0.* instead of 192.168.0.0/24
With and without indentation after the Match statement

If I change PasswordAuthentication to true (outside extraConfig) it allows logging in with a password (sanity).
The match statement seems to be working since without it I can't even input the password, but currently even though it allows me to input my password, I get "Permission denied, please try again" every time.
Edit:
Here's the output from sshd -d (at least since the connection was attempted).
Connection from 192.168.0.140 port 55201 on 192.168.0.12 port 22 rdomain ""
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.8
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 997/997 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT received [preauth]
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3 [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received [preauth]
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: ext-info-in-auth@openssh.com=<0> [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user user service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: connection from 192.168.0.140 matched 'Address 192.168.0.0/24' at line 34
debug1: kex_server_update_ext_info: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
debug1: PAM: initializing for "user"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.0.140"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user user service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for user: Authentication failure
Failed password for user from 192.168.0.140 port 55201 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user user service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for user: Authentication failure
Failed password for user from 192.168.0.140 port 55201 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user user service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 3 failures 2 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for user: Authentication failure
Failed password for user from 192.168.0.140 port 55201 ssh2
Connection closed by authenticating user user 192.168.0.140 port 55201 [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 1822891


If you want to diagnose sshd behavior, you should run it directly with sshd -d. The resulting verbose output should shed some light on what’s going on.

@DanielB I added the output from running sshd -d.

You may have to add more ds to get the required verbosity. Since it looks like PAM is rejecting the login, more logging there could also be of use, but I’m not sure how to get that. It wouldn’t appear in sshd -d either way, but in syslog/journal.

if you are using something like tailscale you can configure your firewall to only allow ssh from that network, like i use  this config on my computers to acces them with password remotly
{ config, pkgs, ... }:
{
  networking.firewall.interfaces."tailscale0".allowedTCPPorts = config.services.openssh.ports;
  services.openssh = {
    enable = true;
    openFirewall = false; # set it up so it is only accessible in tailscale
    settings = {
      X11Forwarding = true;
      PasswordAuthentication = true;
      KbdInteractiveAuthentication = true;
    };
  };
}

